# How can you tell if a trigger is enabled in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, status

My googling-fu is failing me.  How to know if a PostgreSQL trigger is disabled or not?

Comment: are the triggers enabled by default while creating em? Is explicit ALTER TABLE ENABLE TRIGGER necessary?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's my first day with postresql, but I think you can check the trigger state via pg_trigger system table: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-trigger.html

The columns you will need are `tgrelid` and `tgenabled`.

Answer (score 24):

The SQL below will do the work. It displays all triggers in your current database.

```
SELECT pg_namespace.nspname, pg_class.relname, pg_trigger.*
FROM pg_trigger
JOIN pg_class ON pg_trigger.tgrelid = pg_class.oid
JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
```

If *tgenabled* is 'D', the trigger is disabled. All other values (documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-trigger.html)) indicate, that it is enabled in some way.

BTW. If you want to check the triggers for a specific table, the query is a bit shorter:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_trigger
WHERE tgrelid = 'your_schema.your_table'::regclass
```

The *cast* to the [*regclass*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) type gets you from *qualified table name* to OID (object id) the easy way.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT  tgenabled
    FROM    pg_trigger
    WHERE   tgname='your_unique_trigger_name' AND
            tgenabled != 'D'
);
```

If you know the trigger name is unique the above will return true (t) if the *your_unique_trigger_name* trigger is enabled:

```
 exists
--------
 t
(1 row)
```

If disabled it would return false (f).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @tolgayilmaz reply I created a simply function to be used around my project

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_exists_on_table(schema_name text, table_name text, trigger_name text)
RETURNS boolean AS
$body$
declare
    _sql text;
    _boolean_exists boolean;
begin
    _sql := format('
        SELECT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM pg_trigger
            WHERE tgrelid = ''%s.%s''::regclass AND tgname = ''%s'' AND tgenabled != ''D''
        )
    ', schema_name, table_name, trigger_name);

    execute _sql into _boolean_exists;

    return _boolean_exists;
end
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but I just want to share a maybe good answer :)

So the query

```sql
-- for a specific table_name
select tgname, tgenabled from pg_trigger where tgrelid = '[table_name]'::regclass and tgisinternal = false;

-- for all your triggers
select tgname, tgenabled from pg_trigger where tgisinternal = false;
```

So what is different

- where not internal, which means only your triggers

Important to read the docs on that [system table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-trigger.html) `column tgenabled`.

- O => this is an O(ooooh) not a 0(zero)
- D => disabled